# Using URL::to base URL in a Command in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using a custom artisan [Command](http://four.laravel.com/docs/commands) that send an email, and in the template of that email, I need to use `URL::to()` helper method. 
The problem is, when this URL is generated by artisan command, the baseurl is fulfilled with the IP of server instead of domain.

Comment: config/app.php? --> 'url' => 'http://localhost'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it... just change de 'url' key on the file 'app/config/app.php' like Antonio Carlos RIbeiro said...